# How to change color of tr(s) after alternate two tr?

Tags: html, css

i want to change color of tr after two alternate tr that is for first
   two tr color=5 th and 6th tr my try is

```
   .tr1:nth-child(even)  {
       background-color: #e0e0eb; }
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: first two `tr` , color is example red, second two `tr` color is blue, is that what you want ?

Comment: i have n number of trs (table rows) in while loop,i want to to change color after every even tr .for eg color of first and second should red color and then for 3rd and 4th need yellow color then again for 5th and 6th it shoild come red

Comment: @niceman :exactely..

Comment: I hope that question helps :)

Comment: yes its working as like i want

Answer (score -1):

If you want to stick with `nth-child` and continually change the `<tr>` color every two rows you could always do something like this:

```
tr { background: #00ff00; }
tr:nth-child(3), tr:nth-child(4) { background: #ff0000; }
tr:nth-child(5), tr:nth-child(6) { background: #ffff00; }
tr:nth-child(7), tr:nth-child(8) { background: #0000ff; }
```

The first is the 'default' color, the next three specific the colors of rows 3-4, 5-6, 7-8.  The problem I see would be if you're handling this dynamically and have a large quantity of rows... you potentially run into an issue with having to create a lot of CSS to handle whatever number of possible rows you have.

If that is the case I might almost see it as a better option to either place the color styles inline (eww), or create a few CSS classes and apply them every two rows, knowing that they'd end up having to repeat themselves.